# Adding APC to Symfony project causes Fatal Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, apc

Very new to Symfony so apologies if the answer is obvious. I am trying to add APC to a project to see if it improves performance. I am running symfony with easyphp on Windows 7/Windows 8 (installed on usb).
APC is installed in ext folder and added to php.ini file as:

```
extension=php_apc.dll
```

then at end of file:

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 128M
apc.max_file_size = 5M
apc.stat = 1
```

php works fine with these settings. However when I now try to load my Symfony project I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain in 
F:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\projects\SymfonyProj\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain.php line 36
```

Not sure if I have my caching set up all wrong or I am missing some config options somewhere?

Comment: [Configuring APC for Symfony 2](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/configuring-apc-cache/)

Comment: Read this and understand principle btu seems project is set to use composer class loader. Have tired using the recommended settigns from linked page and other sources but they just seem ot introduce other errors. Does the composer class loader do a similar job as apc - if not is there wokr around?

Comment: That error might be not related to APC. I had similar error when adding some Zend components into a symfony project. Weird thing is the error happen only on the first symfony cache:clear command.

Comment: If you're sure it is related to APC, try to restart Apache.